# Prestashop : Declaration of AdminLoginControllerCore::viewAccess() must be compatible with AdminControllerCore:

Tags: error-handling, prestashop

I was using prestashop on hosting with no problem.
Now I started my home web server and I'm trying to get it working.

I tried many different prestashop versions and reinstalled them x times..
All the time problem is that, I can Access front panel, but not the backend panel..

All the time it shows Http 500 ERROR : Server can't Handle this request. 
Now I enabled debugging and it shows me error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of AdminLoginControllerCore::viewAccess() must be compatible with AdminControllerCore::viewAccess($disable = false) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Shop\controllers\admin\AdminLoginController.php on line 27
```

And Line

```
class AdminLoginControllerCore extends AdminController{
```

**I can't understand why this is happening, becouse I haven't edited and changed any file or folder.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you have to implement a method in a child class with all parameters of a parent class method. So in your parent class viewAccess has a parameter `$disable=false` and you need to have it in your child `viewAccess()` declaration. Just put that parameter in the declaration `public function viewAccess($disable=false)` and you even need not use it inside. And why it was not showing on the hosting but show in a local machine it is sooner in due to different PHP versions on the servers. Because in different versions it has different error levels.

Comment: Thank you very much! Was struggling with this for a week. Didn't expected so simple solution

Answer (score 2):

The way to fix this is simple:

go to ROOT/controllers\admin\AdminLoginController.php
al line 153 you’ll have to change
public function `viewAccess()`  to  public function `viewAccess($disable = false)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue with a fresh installation of PS 1.7 yesterday but did'nt come out of it. Today, apparently the same one with PS 1.6.18, thought I was expecting it would'nt, but it seems that PS can't stand PHP 7.2.4, no matter which PS version it is (of course I should have guessed that a previous version would'nt make it better than a recent one ...). Some PHP warnings might have turned into fatal errors now. The fact is, when I went into `controllers/admin/adminLoginController` on line 153 and typed `public function viewAccess($disable = false)` instead of `public function viewAccess()` the blank screen went away and my back-office was there (with some remaining warnings ...). Those files would'nt have to be overwritten to allow upgrade, but anyway 1.6.18 is the last upgrade of 1.6 series... Hope it can help.